# Default HostnameVerifier

Tags: android, ssl, hostname, android-security

I was going through below article-
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl
and found below text-

> Replacing HostnameVerifier can be very dangerous if the other virtual
>   host is not under your control, because a man-in-the-middle attack
>   could direct traffic to another server without your knowledge.

If we are not setting `urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);` in code on client side , then is there any default Hostname Verifier at client side as the doc talks of replacing HostnameVerifier?If yes,how does default HostnameVerifier works?

Comment: Note that Google support FAQ [reads](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426): *If you have technical questions about the vulnerability, you can post to Stack Overflow and use the tag “android-security.” For clarification on steps you need to take to resolve this issue, you can contact our developer support team.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are not setting your custom hostname verifier, the HttpsUrlConnection will use <s>[DefaultHostnameVerifier](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore2/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/javax/net/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier.java)</s> [OkHostnameVerifier](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/refs/heads/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/tls/OkHostnameVerifier.java).

This is actually the best practice – to leave this verification to the platform.

The legitimate exceptions may be when you add extra layers of protection on top of the default verifier, e.g. when you want to enforce some sort of custom
certificate pinning (but why would you not follow the [best practices](https://mailapurvpandey.medium.com/ssl-pinning-in-android-90dddfa3e051) that don't involve this?).

There are very few situations where you may want to loosen the default checks a bit, e.g. if you, just [like Google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore2/+/b5de22c2a7fbe35f0dc8d3585e4bd9aa0966fc90/luni/src/main/java/javax/net/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier.java#157) [few years ago](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/cc0952ec282184914a6153e9deff458c94785fd1), have some subdomains that don't have SNI and must be treated as the main domain.